# Can a Monster carry more than one Sample at a time?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

The **Take Sample** keeper action does not seem to have a restriction around having more than one sample, other than it would require multiple turns.

> Action: One per turn, choose a monster in an investigator's space. 
>    Place 1 sample token on the monster and then move it 1 space.

Following on from the above, if the monster does have more than one sample token on it at the start of your turn can you turn them all in at the same time for 5 threat each?

> If the Monster is in an altar's space at the start of your turn, place the token on the altar and again 5 threat.

This seemed clear but a little strong for the keeper in our initial game of Mansions when playing the Fall of House Lynch 1B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**,

You are playing this correctly on both counts.  A monster can carry more than one sample, see the rules on page 12

> When a monster with sample tokens is killed, all its 
>   sample tokens are discarded.

The trade in for 5 threat is automatic and should be used for all samples carried by a monster on the altar's space.

Answer (score 0):

The rules imply pretty heavily that you can take multiple samples. As for dumping them, that's not so clear.

Personally, if the players are new and don't know all the rules, or are struggling, I would just remove one sample per turn to give them a chance to break in and stop you.